# vba how to look for a code in various sheets and paste them in another

Tags: excel, vba

so i'm trying to use a macro to look in sheets one code and paste the information of that code , I'm trying to use a simple macro with advanced filters to do that, but the problem is that when the information of one sheet is pasted the next one gets pasted right in front of the last one, I'd like it to paste the info in the next row, but since it needs the same titles i can't seem to do it.
What i have right now:

```
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Hoja2").Range("Tabla1[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("Hoja1!Criteria"), copytorange:=Range("C6:E6"), _
        Unique:=False
    Range("C1000", "E1000").End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2).Range("C1").Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Hoja3").Range("Tabla2[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("Hoja1!Criteria"), copytorange:=Range("C6:E6") _
        , Unique:=False
```

This is an example image  since I can't put the info in here (sorry if my english is not very good)

[image]

Comment: Because you are always pasting to the same range `copytorange:=Range("C6:E6")`.

Comment: Yes Inedeed, but how can i possibly paste in the same range but different cells, like the next one that is empty?

Comment: `the same range but different cells` That doesn't make sense. Anyways, find the last row/column then +1.